# Call to show fancyBox

Tags: javascript, html

I havent worked with FancyBox's for a while, and am not really 100% up to speed on Javascript either.

However i have an icon that i want to use to show a div in a fancy box.

this is the code i have right now

```
</a><span style='font-size: 20px; color: darkgreen'><a href="#"><i id="toEmail" onclick="openEmailAddressList" class="fa fa-users sameRow margin10"></i><a/></span>

<div class="emailAddresses">

</div>
```

then in my javascript file

```
 $("#emailAddresses").fancybox({
    openEffect: "none",
    closeEffect: "none",
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: "outside"
        }
    }

});
```

if i change `#emailAddresses` to `#toEmail` then i get the icon in the fancy box, but thats not what i am after.

any and all help appreciated

Comment: you start with `</a>`

Comment: Where is the `#emailAddresses` element?

Comment: just added it to the question

Comment: dont know how the bad </a> got  in there but i have changed that now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the fancy box with a click you can use:

```
$('#toEmail').click(function() {
    $('#emailAddresses').fancybox({
        openEffect: "none",
        closeEffect: "none",
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: "outside"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to keep the `onclick` inline like you have it for some reason, then you'd need to initialize the fancybox in the `openEmailAddressList` function:

```
function openEmailAddressList() {
    $('#emailAddresses').fancybox({
        openEffect: "none",
        closeEffect: "none",
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: "outside"
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to find an old solution of mine,

the javascript im calling is this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    parent: "form:first" // jQuery selector
});
```

});

the link to get it is now this

```
<a href="#emailAddresses" class="fancybox"><span style='font-size: 20px; color: darkgreen'><i id="toEmail" class="fa fa-users sameRow margin10"></i></span></a>
```

and the div is coded like this at the moment just to get something to pop up

```
<div class="emailAddresses" id="emailAddresses" style="display: none; padding: 5px;">
        <p>something</p>
</div>
```